# Adding an existing image to a Canvas

Tags: java, image, canvas

Greetings I have recently been trying to put an image from my computer onto a Canvas in Java, I have the image, spaceship.jpeg in the folder where my class is located and can not seem to get it to display. Here's my code...

```
public class DrawingImages extends Canvas{

  public static Image img;

  public static void main(String[] args){

    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
    window.getContentPane().add(new DrawingImages());
    window.setVisible(true);

    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new URL("spaceship.jpeg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
     g.drawImage(img, 0, 100, this);
  }

}
```

FYI I am also using the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changed the "look" of your window but the window doesn't know anything about this change yet.

Just do `window.repaint();` at the end of your main method, which will take care of calling the `paint()` method.

Comment: It might be nice to elaborate *why* this is necessary.